# Android Studio Design preview stops working when the emulator is started

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, editor, emulation

I searched for similar problems but I couldn't find anything related, so I decided to ask here.

Today, when I updated Android Studio to 3.4.1 (stable version) I noticed that, when I start the emulator, my design preview stops working. I have to close the emulator e restart Android studio to make the design preview work again.

Have any one noticed a problem like that? Is there somehwere I can check in Android Studio for possible errors that might be happening? I checked the logs and couldn't find anything.

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I couldn't find any information about this problem and then decided to use Android Studio 3.5 beta 4 which doesn't have this problem. So, whatever the problem is, it was fixed by this version.

Android Studio 3.5 beta 4 solved my problem.

Comment: I think I talked too soon... Even on 3.5. beta 4 I'm still seeing this problem... :(

Comment: I noticed, in the button where you choose between design and blueprint options, there is an option called "Force Refresh Layout" with the shortcut assigned to the "R" letter. That solved my problem! :)